# Выгрузка отчета из 1с в Excel

Tags: excel, 1с, vba

Есть тестовый макрос, выгрузки данных из 1С. Он работает.
Не могу понять как мне выгрузить данные отчета???
В моем понимании получается нужно:
1. Сформировать отчет за текущий день
2. Выгрузить сформированный отчет

```
Public v7 As Object

Sub ConnectV77_1()
Dim i
i = 4
Set v7 = CreateObject("v82.COMConnector")

Set result = v7.Connect("Srvr=""bit"";Ref=""BitFinans""")

Set res = result.newObject("Запрос")
res.Text = "ВЫБРАТЬ Наименование ИЗ Справочник.Контрагенты"
Set finish = res.Execute()
Set kontragenty = finish.Unload()

For Each k In kontragenty
    For Each i In k

    Next
Next



Set v7 = Nothing

Set result = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно выгрузить отчет, а не данные запроса, то кажется проще сформировать в 1С табличный документ и сохранить его в  формате Эксель, а уже с ним работать.
Для управления этим из Эксель, можно сделать соответствующую экспортную процедуру.

Если же идти по пути макроса, приведенного в вопросе, то нужно сделать запрос, который выведет поля примитивного типа, и идти как в макросе:

> For Each k In kontragenty
>   k - строка таблицы значений, все еще объект 1С, а k.Наименование уже наименование контрагента, строка. Можно спокойно обрабатывать Excel'ем.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно программно сохранять отчет сформированный по можно так:

```
    МойОтчет = Отчеты.ОтчетПоЗП.Создать();
//ФормаОтчета = МойОтчет.ПолучитьФорму("ФормаОтчета");
СхемаКомпоновкиДанных = МойОтчет.ПолучитьМакет("ОсновнаяСхемаКомпоновкиДанных");

//Из схемы возьмем настройки по умолчанию
МойОтчет.КомпоновщикНастроек.Настройки.ПараметрыДанных.Элементы[0].Значение = НачалоДня(ТекущаяДата());
МойОтчет.КомпоновщикНастроек.Настройки.ПараметрыДанных.Элементы[1].Значение = КонецДня(ТекущаяДата());
МойОтчет.КомпоновщикНастроек.Настройки.ПараметрыДанных.Элементы[2].Значение = Справочники.ФизическиеЛица.ПустаяСсылка();

ДанныеРасшифровки = Новый ДанныеРасшифровкиКомпоновкиДанных;

//Формируем макет, с помощью компоновщика макета
КомпоновщикМакета = Новый КомпоновщикМакетаКомпоновкиДанных;

//Передаем в макет компоновки схему, настройки и данные расшифровки
МакетКомпоновки = КомпоновщикМакета.Выполнить(СхемаКомпоновкиДанных,
МойОтчет.КомпоновщикНастроек.Настройки, ДанныеРасшифровки);

//Выполним компоновку с помощью процессора компоновки
ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных = Новый ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных;
ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных.Инициализировать(МакетКомпоновки,,
ДанныеРасшифровки);

//Очищаем поле табличного документа
//Результат = ФормаОтчета.ЭлементыФормы.Результат;
//Результат.Очистить();
табДок = Новый ТабличныйДокумент;


//Выводим результат в табличный документ
ПроцессорВывода = Новый ПроцессорВыводаРезультатаКомпоновкиДанныхВТабличныйДокумент;
ПроцессорВывода.УстановитьДокумент(табДок);

ПроцессорВывода.Вывести(ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных);
Попытка
    табДок.Записать(Константы.тиПутьХраненияОтчетовПоЗП.Получить() + "ОтчетПоЗП за " + Строка(Год(ТекущаяДата())) + 
    "_" + Строка(Месяц(ТекущаяДата())) +
    "_" + Строка(День(ТекущаяДата())) +
    "-" + Строка(Час(ТекущаяДата())) +
    "-" + Строка(Минута(ТекущаяДата())) +
    "-" + Строка(Секунда(ТекущаяДата())) +
    ".xls", ТипФайлаТабличногоДокумента.XLS);
Исключение
КонецПопытки;
```